# How do i merge all vertex color layers?

Tags: vertex-colors

I have three layers, i tried using the Data Transfer modifier to combine them all into one, but it ended up with Strongly Highlighted...

SOMEBODY HELP!!!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[[image]

Edit: I wanna achieve the same result as original in combined. I use the same blend modes in the original.

[image]

Comment: Are your layers R,G,&B?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You've set the _Mix Mode_ to _Add_, so of course colors will get brighter if you add them together... what is the result you want/need/expect?

Comment: Please don't scream help, every post on this platform is supposed to help.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, but i used the same blend modes....

Comment: @RobinBetts, yes, but i don't think you can split channels.

Comment: If this is is clean, R00,0G0,00B, adding should be fine.. I think the problem may be that vertex colors are stored as sRGB.